# How does user profile reference counting works?

Tags: winapi, impersonation

We have services to start processes with `LoadUserProfile()`. Those services calls `UnloadUserProfile()` if process terminates, then terminates services themselves.

Everything works fine there. Also with multiple services. But if we use same user account by multiple services then randomly a problem occurs. Possibly if one of the service that uses same user account, restarts or stops.

The problem is user profile is unloaded randomly in a (our) service, then the process that is started from the service, has no more access to user profile. For example problems by HKCU-accesses for the loaded user.

Note: Services that i'm talking about are only our services.

Our service(s) calls `LoadUserProfile()` by starting and `UnloadUserProfile()` by stopping. As @RbMm pointed that unload is not necessary, but should not be the problem even if we call it ourselves.

Thanks to @RbMm for the ReferenceCounting info. (Which were not documented in `LoadUserProfile()`-documentation)

To solve my problem i need to understand reference counting. Imagine that a user account profile loaded by 2 processes or services. I will use service here.

I need to learn what will be happend by these states;

**1:** **ServiceX** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceY** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceX** calls `UnloadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceX** stops. RefCount?

**2:** **ServiceX** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceY** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceX** calls `UnloadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceX** calls `UnloadUserProfile()` one more time, then **ServiceX** stops. RefCount?

**3:** **ServiceX** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceY** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceX** stops. RefCount?

**4:** **ServiceX** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceY** calls `LoadUserProfile()`, then **ServiceX** calls `LoadUserProfile()` one more time, then **ServiceX** stops. RefCount?

Can anybody explain it?

Comment: User Profile have reference counting. every `LoadUserProfile` increment it reference count and `UnloadUserProfile` decrement. the profile actually unloaded only when `RefCount` become zero. so even if some another service call `LoadUserProfile` and `UnloadUserProfile` this not affect profile, until you hold reference on it (not call `UnloadUserProfile` yourself). and if exist registry keys opened in profile hive - it will be not unloaded

Comment: `Or how can we prevent that other processes unload the profile that we are using?` - nothing need todo - you hold reference to profile, until not call `UnloadUserProfile` yourself

Comment: @RbMm i couldn't find any documentation about reference counting. I don't understand why we don't have profile loaded, even if we unload the profile ourselves, if there is reference counting. ServiceX loads ProfileA and starts AppX (RefCount:1), then ServiceY loads ProfileA and starts AppY (RefCount:2). AppX stops running and ServiceX unloads the Profile and stops (RefCount:1). Here we have no more profile loaded by AppY. Does OS decrement the reference count one more time if service stops? Otherwise reference count should be ok. Thanks for the help. I will try without unloading the Profile.

Comment: of course profile have reference counting. you  can view under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<sid>` exist `RefCount REG_DWORD`. you can view that after success `LoadUserProfileW` the `RefCount` is incremented on 1 and after `UnloadUserProfile` `RefCount` is decremented on 1. you can view this direct in *regedit* or say use next [code](https://pastebin.com/MqiN4DRi) for test

Comment: `Does OS decrement the reference count one more time if service stops?` - of course no. no any relationship between some service and some user profile. why os must unload some profile when service stop ? which profile ? are possible get `profile=fn(service)` ?

Comment: services that i'm talking about, are our services. Those services uses LoadUserProfile and UnloadUserProfile. Profile means user profile. I think our analyze is false. I need more debugging. Thanks for the help

Comment: `I think our analyze is false.` - in what concrete false ? that refcount is used ? this is 100% fact. and you can easy view this yourself - in registry editor and/or by code which i paste. and really this is absolute logical and native solution - what will be if one application call and use `LoadUserProfile` and another `UnloadUserProfile` in concurrent ? really only reference counting here is solution. if something wrong worked for you - error in your code (say unpaired call to Load/Unload etc)

Comment: yet another example of refcount [here](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2009/11/05/windows-installer-proxy-information-not-correctly-registered/)